# bash script fails to delete s3 object inside a while loop

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have text a file with a list of s3 objects, in the form of:

```
prefix_x/prefix_y/file_name_1 
prefix_w/prefix_z/file_name_88
etc...
```

I wrote a bash script to delete all of these objects, as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash

LIST_OF_PATHS=$1

while read FILE_PATH; do
  aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/$FILE_PATH
done < $LIST_OF_PATHS
```

The script doesn't seem to delete the objects (they appear in the UI and in the terminal when `ls`ing them with the CLI).

Further details and things I've already tried:

- deleting the objects manually with similar command in the CLI - it works.
- adding `ls` command to the loop provides no output, whereas typing this command manually on the very same files does give output.
- adding sleep 0.1 to each iteration of the loop didn't help either.
- of course the script runs - I see the output: `delete: s3://bucket-name/prefix_x/prefix_y/file_name_1`, but the file doesn't actually get deleted.
- running a simpler bash script with the same command and a specific file name (not inside a loop) does delete successfully.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script so you can see the commands as they're executing.

Comment: Probably not the problem here, but quote your variables and use `read -r` as suggested by https://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: Does the text file have any weird formatting (like [DOS/Windows line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)) or invisible "gremlin" characters in it? Try printing it with `LC_ALL=C cat -vet /path/to/textfile` -- you should see a "$" at the end of each line, but anything else indicates trouble (DOS/Windows line endings will look like "^M$"). P.s. I second the `set -x` suggestion.

Comment: @Benjamin : Could it be that you have spaces in your `FILE_PATH`? But it is weird that you don't get any error message.....

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

The issue was that in a script, bash expects the newline char to be '\n', but my input file contained '\r' at the end of each line. More on this can be found here:
https://superuser.com/questions/489180/remove-r-from-echoing-out-in-bash-script/489191

Many thanks to @Barmar, whose comment helped me see this and debug the issue.

I simply changed input file itself, and the script ran perfectly as it was.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your AWS permissions on the S3 service.
2. Check your AWS command line tool configuration.
3. Check your s3 bucket configuration.
4. Run your AWS s3 command without using a loop, see if the command is run successfully, before using a loop

Comment: I tried all these (and other) dry-runs, as I mentioned in my question. Thanks!